# Parent grid doesn't take child's min-content width into account

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In Chrome and Safari, a parent styled with `display: grid` doesn't seem to take into account the fact that its child is `width: min-content` when calculating its own width or its children's positions. See for yourself:

```css
#parent {
  position: absolute;
  background: lightgreen;
  display: grid;
  
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#child {
  padding: 25px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px red;
  
  width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    <p>hello jello allegro rhino cello
  </div>
</div>
```

The behavior I would naively expect would be:

- to have the red box (child) aligned to the right (because of `justify-content: flex-end`)
- to have the green box (parent) take the width of the red box (because it simply has no reason to be this wide, except that it's exactly the width of the child if it weren't min-content)

**Question:
Is this an expected behavior? Do the specs say anything about this? Or is this a bug and Firefox got it right?**

---

My assumption is that calculating a grid layout isn't O(1) or even O(n) and browsers need to bail-out early on edge cases, and width: min-content is probably kind of the same thing. But I'm just guessing here.

---

*Bonus points if you can point me in the direction of an open ticket for this "bug" in either of the 3 big browsers!*

Comment: since the behavior is different on Firefox then it's either a bug or a not well defined behavior but I vote for a bug

Comment: @Paulie_D can you explain why the tags were incorrect? The question is as much about W3C / browser implementations as it is about css grid.

Comment: It's not about the W3C, at best you might want to add browser specific tags since they seem to differ in their implementation (possibly).

Comment: If anyone is interested, i opened a ticket on chromium's tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1209443